# Angular App with Bootstrap Dynamic Tabs Navigation

Tags: angular, routes, tabs, bootstrap-4, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a SPA with Angular and Bootstrap. 
I have a menu with links. When the user clicks the link, the new Bootstrap Dynamic Tab opens and it's content is . Now, i want to add some navigation INSIDE the tab. For example:

I have a Sale-Register Component. Inside it i have four links to other components. I want to open the links location (eg. routerLink='path_to_component') INSIDE the same bootstrap tab's content.

Any solutions how to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [Multiple Router Outlets](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#multiple-outlets) for this.

You need add a named router outlet to your Sale-Register Component like:

```html
<router-outlet name='outletname'></router-outlet>
```

Then you also need to define which component to load in your Routes array like:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "page", component: PageComponent }, // This is your primary outlet's definition
  {
    path: "tabpage",
    component: TabPageComponent,
    outlet: "outletname" // This is where you define which outlet to use
  }
]
```

Finally update the navigation link to use your outlet:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['page'], outletname: ['tabpage'] } }]">
  Link to the tab
</a>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. The problem is that i know how to open and navigate to the tab, but  I just want to switch the component from Sale-Register Component to eg. OfferChoose Component in the same tab content div.

Comment: @DariuszLewicki I think what you need is simply just nesting routes then, could you check this demo out? https://codesandbox.io/s/q8xqq2no46 This is what you need?